# How to group DataFrame by a period of time?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data from log files and would like to group entries by a minute:

```
 def gen(date, count=10):
     while count > 0:
         yield date, "event{}".format(randint(1,9)), "source{}".format(randint(1,3))
         count -= 1
         date += DateOffset(seconds=randint(40))

 df = DataFrame.from_records(list(gen(datetime(2012,1,1,12, 30))), index='Time', columns=['Time', 'Event', 'Source'])
```

df:

```
 Event  Source
 2012-01-01 12:30:00     event3  source1
 2012-01-01 12:30:12     event2  source2
 2012-01-01 12:30:12     event2  source2
 2012-01-01 12:30:29     event6  source1
 2012-01-01 12:30:38     event1  source1
 2012-01-01 12:31:05     event4  source2
 2012-01-01 12:31:38     event4  source1
 2012-01-01 12:31:44     event5  source1
 2012-01-01 12:31:48     event5  source2
 2012-01-01 12:32:23     event6  source1
```

I tried these options:

1. `df.resample('Min')` is too high level and wants to aggregate.
2. `df.groupby(date_range(datetime(2012,1,1,12, 30), freq='Min',
   periods=4))` fails with exception.
3. `df.groupby(TimeGrouper(freq='Min'))` works fine and returns a `DataFrameGroupBy` object for further processing, e.g.:

   ```
   grouped = df.groupby(TimeGrouper(freq='Min'))
   grouped.Source.value_counts()
   2012-01-01 12:30:00  source1    1
   2012-01-01 12:31:00  source2    2
                        source1    2
   2012-01-01 12:32:00  source2    2
                        source1    2
   2012-01-01 12:33:00  source1    1
   ```

*However*, the `TimeGrouper` class is not documented.

What is the correct way to group by a period of time? How can I group the data by a minute AND by the Source column, e.g. `groupby([TimeGrouper(freq='Min'), df.Source])`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can group on any array/Series of the same length as your DataFrame --- even a computed factor that's not actually a column of the DataFrame.  So to group by minute you can do:

```
df.groupby(df.index.map(lambda t: t.minute))
```

If you want to group by minute and something else, just mix the above with the column you want to use:

```
df.groupby([df.index.map(lambda t: t.minute), 'Source'])
```

Personally I find it useful to just add columns to the DataFrame to store some of these computed things (e.g., a "Minute" column) if I want to group by them often, since it makes the grouping code less verbose.

Or you could try something like this:

```
df.groupby([df['Source'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='Min')])
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the result I was looking for with this statement: df.groupby([df.index.map(lambda t: datetime(t.year, t.month, t.day, t.hour, t.minute)), df.Source, df.Event]).size().unstack(level=2)

Comment: how can i extend it to 30 minutes ?

Comment: This pd.TimeGrouper can be used to group by multiples of time units `df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30Min'))`

Comment: I want to group data by days, but my day ends at 02:00 not at 24:00. How can this be done?

Comment: TimeGrouper is deprecated since pandas 21 (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/v0.21.0.html#deprecations) - would pdGrouper be a drop in replacement here?

Comment: I get the error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'minute'
 when applying this to my DF, DF.groupby([DF.index.map(lambda t: t.minute), 'Time']). What can be wrong here?

Comment: @Baobab: Probably your column is not a datetime column but an int column.

Comment: @serguei Agreed. Otherwise data with different hours and days would be grouped together if they have the same minute if you do `df.groupby(df.index.map(lambda t: t.minute))`. Honestly just use `pd.Grouper` -- it's much easier.

Answer (score 28):

Since the original answer is rather old and pandas introduced [periods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Period.html)
a different solution is nowadays:

```
df.groupby(df.index.to_period('T'))
```

Additionally, you can [resample](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
df.resample('T')
```

Answer (score 19):

pd.TimeGrouper is now depreciated. Here is v1.05 update using [pd.Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html)

```py
df['Date'] = df.index

df.groupby(['Source',pd.Grouper(key = 'Date', freq='30min')])
```