# Grouping dataframe by custom date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe that I'm trying to combine date in one instance by minute and the other by 30  minutes.

```
df = pd.read_csv('2015-09-01.csv', header=None,\
                    names=['ID','CITY', 'STATE', 'TIMESTAMP','TWEET'], \
                    low_memory=False, \
                    parse_dates=['TIMESTAMP'], usecols=['STATE','TIMESTAMP','TWEET'])
```

**Method 1**

I have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073609/how-to-group-dataframe-by-a-period-of-time) solution but if I try the following:

```
df = df2.groupby([df2.TIMESTAMP,pd.TimeGrouper(freq='H')])
```

It results in this error:

```
TypeError: axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'Int64Index
```

which is very weird because `TIMESTAMP` is being parsed in `read_csv`

**Method 2**

I tried setting `TIMESTAMP` into index then doing:

```
df = df2.groupby([df2.index,pd.TimeGrouper(freq='H')])
```

However it's not coming up right as len(df) is `1350` rather than `24` since the dataframe as a whole is from 1 day worth of data.

**Method 3**

I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391969/how-to-group-pandas-dataframe-entries-by-date-in-a-non-unique-column) solution but I'm not sure how to set it into 30 minute interval:

```
df = df2.groupby(df2['TIMESTAMP'].map(lambda x: x.hour))
```

*Sample Data*

```
STATE,TIMESTAMP,TWEET
0,TX,2015-09-25 00:00:01,Wish I could have gone to the game
1,USA,2015-09-25 00:00:01,PSA:  @HaileyCassidyy and I are not related in...
2,USA,2015-09-25 00:00:02,If you gonna fail don't bring some one down wi...
3,NJ,2015-09-25 00:00:02,@_falastinia hol up hol up I can't listen to t...
4,USA,2015-09-25 00:00:02,"Wind 0.0 mph ---. Barometer 30.235 in, Rising ..."
5,NJ,2015-09-25 00:00:03,WHY ISNT GREYS ANATOMY ON?!
6,MI,2015-09-25 00:00:03,@cody_cole06 you bet it is
7,WA,2015-09-25 00:00:04,"Could be worse, I guess, could be in a collisi..."
8,NY,2015-09-25 00:00:04,I'm totally using this graphic some day... tha...
9,USA,2015-09-25 00:00:04,@MKnightOwl @Andromehda LMAO I honestly didn't..
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To group a column by a frequency, you need to pass its name to the `key` parameter of the `Grouper`, like this:

```
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='TIMESTAMP', freq='30T'))
```

Edit:

See the [`Grouper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#grouping-with-a-grouper-specification) docs for more -  but in general, when you do `groupby([a,b])` you are grouping by the *unique combinations* of `a` and `b`.

So in your example you were grouping by all the unique timestamp values (`df['TIMESTAMP']`)
and a time grouper to the index (`pd.TimeGrouper` defaults to the index if no key is specified) - the `TypeError` was because your index was not datetimelike.

This also is why you were getting the large number of groups after setting the index to `'TIMESTAMP'`.

Comment: Yes, that works. I tried `df2.groupby([df2['TIMESTAMP'],pd.TimeGrouper(freq='H')])` it was giving me TypeError, ever after doing `df2['TIMESTAMP'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['TIMESTAMP']`. Any idea why?