# Count number of records in a specific time interval in Python

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am reading from a csv file which contains the following data:

```
Create Date,           Original Filesize,  Number of Encodings
2016-01-27 16:27:10,   855583191,          1
2016-01-27 16:28:11,   854336,             1
2016-01-27 16:28:25,   854336,             1
2016-01-27 16:30:12,   9691559,            1
```

I want to count the number of records generated every two minutes in the table.

E.g. if we start from `2016-01-27 16:27:00`
then from `2016-01-27 16:27:01` to `2016-01-27 16:29:00`, we have `2` records. 
from `2016-01-27 16:29:01` to `2016-01-27 16:31:00`, we have `1` record and so on.

I am trying to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) as I want to do some data analysis on it later. Is there an easy way to do this with/without pandas?

Also, I use `mysql` to export this data in the first place. If it is easier using `sql`, that is also ok.

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073609/how-to-group-dataframe-by-a-period-of-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sum.html):

```
print df.resample('2min').sum()
                     Original Filesize  Number of Encodings
Create Date                                                
2016-01-27 16:26:00          855583191                    1
2016-01-27 16:28:00            1708672                    2
2016-01-27 16:30:00            9691559                    1

print df.resample('2min', base=1).sum()
                     Original Filesize  Number of Encodings
Create Date                                                
2016-01-27 16:27:00          857291863                    3
2016-01-27 16:29:00            9691559                    1
```

Or if you need aggregate only column `Number of Encodings`:

```
print df.resample('2min')['Number of Encodings'].sum().reset_index()
          Create Date  Number of Encodings
0 2016-01-27 16:26:00                    1
1 2016-01-27 16:28:00                    2
2 2016-01-27 16:30:00                    1

print df.resample('2min', base=1)['Number of Encodings'].sum().reset_index()
          Create Date  Number of Encodings
0 2016-01-27 16:27:00                    3
1 2016-01-27 16:29:00                    1
```

More universal is aggregate by [`size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html), if you need only count rows:

```
print df.resample('2min').size().reset_index(name='count')
          Create Date  count
0 2016-01-27 16:26:00      1
1 2016-01-27 16:28:00      2
2 2016-01-27 16:30:00      1

print df.resample('2min', base=1).size().reset_index(name='count')
          Create Date  count
0 2016-01-27 16:27:00      3
1 2016-01-27 16:29:00      1
```

Comment: elegant answer, +1. I went through `cut` but it requires more than a line!