# Group data by time of the day

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, time-series

I have a dataframe with datetime index:`df.head(6)`

```
                          NUMBERES              PRICE    
DEAL_TIME
2015-03-02 12:40:03              5                 25   
2015-03-04 14:52:57              7                 23   
2015-03-03 08:10:09             10                 43   
2015-03-02 20:18:24              5                 37   
2015-03-05 07:50:55              4                 61   
2015-03-02 09:08:17              1                 17
```

The dataframe includes the data of one week. Now I need to count the time period of the day. If time period is 1 hour, I know the following method would work:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby(df.index.hour).count()
```

But I don't know how to do when the time period is half hour. How can I realize it?

**UPDATE:**

I was told that this question is similar to [How to group DataFrame by a period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073609/how-to-group-dataframe-by-a-period-of-time)

But I had tried the methods mentioned. Maybe it's my fault that I didn't say it clearly. 'DEAL_TIME' ranges from '2015-03-02 00:00:00' to '2015-03-08 23:59:59'. If I use `pd.TimeGrouper(freq='30Min')` or `resample()`, the time periods would range from '2015-03-02 00:30' to '2015-03-08 23:30'. But what I want is a series like below:

```
              COUNT      
DEAL_TIME
00:00:00         53 
00:30:00         49 
01:00:00         31
01:30:00         22
02:00:00          1
02:30:00         24
03:00:00         27
03:30:00         41
04:00:00         41
04:30:00         76
05:00:00         33
05:30:00         16
06:00:00         15
06:30:00          4
07:00:00         60
07:30:00         85
08:00:00          3
08:30:00         37
09:00:00         18
09:30:00         29
10:00:00         31
10:30:00         67
11:00:00         35
11:30:00         60
12:00:00         95
12:30:00         37
13:00:00         30
13:30:00         62
14:00:00         58
14:30:00         44
15:00:00         45
15:30:00         35
16:00:00         94
16:30:00         56
17:00:00         64
17:30:00         43
18:00:00         60
18:30:00         52
19:00:00         14
19:30:00          9
20:00:00         31
20:30:00         71
21:00:00         21
21:30:00         32
22:00:00         61
22:30:00         35
23:00:00         14
23:30:00         21
```

In other words, **the time period should be irrelevant to the date.**

Comment: Similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073609/how-to-group-dataframe-by-a-period-of-time

Comment: I have edited my question again. Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Therefore I vote to reopen the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a 30-minute time grouper for this:

```
grouper = pd.TimeGrouper(freq="30T")
```

You also need to remove the 'date' part from the index:

```
df.index = df.reset_index()['index'].apply(lambda x: x - pd.Timestamp(x.date()))
```

Now, you can group by time alone:

```
df.groupby(grouper).count()
```

You can find somewhat obscure `TimeGrouper` documentation here: [pandas resample documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001389/pandas-resample-documentation) (it's actually `resample` documentation, but both features use the same rules).

Comment: No, I know this method. Please read my question again. I have something updated.

Comment: Your method seems to be sense. But index will change to timedelta after removing the 'date', Timegrouper() will return a ValueError:  Inferred frequency None from passed timedeltas does not conform to passed frequency 30T.

Comment: Yes, the index becomes a `timedelta64`. But it does not cause any problems with the grouper (I use pandas 0.18.1). The first row of the result is `07:50:55         2      2`, you can adjust the base if you want the window to start at 00 and 30 minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have benefited a lot.

Answer (score 1):

- In pandas, the most common way to group by time is to use the
  .resample() function.
- In v0.18.0 this function is two-stage.
- This means that df.resample('M') creates an object to which we can
  apply other functions (mean, count, sum, etc.)

The code snippet will be like,

```
df.resample('M').count()
```

You can refer here for [example](https://chrisalbon.com/python/pandas_group_data_by_time.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But this is not what I need. Please read my question again. I have something updated.

Comment: This does not answer the question I'm afraid, what he is looking for is a way to group by 15 minutes over all days (so one 15 min interval should contain the data in that interval over all included days) not just consecutive 15min stretches!