# python getting histogram bins for datetime objects

Tags: python, list, datetime, histogram

I have two lists.

1. The list `times` is a list of `datetimes` from `2018-04-10 00:00` to
   `2018-04-10 23:59`.
2. For each item in `times` I have a corresponding label of `0` or `1` recorded in the list `labels`.

My goal is to get the mean label value (between `0` and `1`) for every minute interval.

```
times = [Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00.118000'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00.547000'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00.569000'),
 Timestamp('2018-04-10 00:00:00.690000'),
.
.
.
Timestamp('2018-04-10 23:59:59.999000') ]

labels = [0,1,1,0,1,0,....1]
```

where `len(times) == len(labels)`

For every minute interval between `2018-04-10 00:00` and `2018-04-10 23:59`, the min and max times in the list respectively, I am trying to get two lists:

1) The start time of the minute interval.

2) The mean average label value of all the datetimes in that interval.

In particular I am having trouble with (2).

*Note: the `times` list is not necessarily chronologically ordered*

Comment: Is `times` sorted?

Comment: `for every minute interval.` - `00:00:00.000` to `00:00:59.999`?, What is a `Timestamp`?

Comment: @wwii no time is not sorted. Yes for every minute interval.

Comment: What is a Timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, I begin with how I generated the data as above format

```
from datetime import datetime
size = int(1e6)

timestamp_a_day = np.linspace(datetime.now().timestamp(), datetime.now().timestamp()+24*60*60, size)
dummy_sec = np.random.rand(size)

timestamp_series = pd.Series(timestamp_a_day + dummy_sec)\
.sort_values().reset_index(drop=True)\
.apply(lambda x: datetime.fromtimestamp(x))

data = pd.DataFrame(timestamp_series, columns=['timestamp'])
data['label'] = np.random.randint(0, 2, size)
```

Let's solve this problem !!!
(I hope I understand your question precisely hahaha)

```
1) data['start_interval'] = data['timestamp'].dt.floor('s')
2) data.groupby('start_interval')['label'].mean()
```

Comment: Related: [Python Pandas: Group datetime column into hour and minute aggregations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266019/python-pandas-group-datetime-column-into-hour-and-minute-aggregations), [How to group DataFrame by a period of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11073609/how-to-group-dataframe-by-a-period-of-time),

Answer (score 1):

- [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) `times` and `labels` then [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted);
- Write a function that returns the date, hour, minute of a Timestamp;
- [groupby](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) that function;
- [sum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) and average the labels for each group